# Understanding and proving the asymptotic behavior of $E[\min(\sum_i X_i, k)]$ for i.i.d. Bernoulli random variables

Tags: probability, asymptotics, expected-value, probability-limit-theorems, bernoulli-distribution

I came across the following equation, where $X_i$ are i.i.d. Bernoulli random variables with probability $\dfrac{k}{n}$ of being $1$:

$$\mathbb{E}\left[\min\left(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i, k\right)\right] \approx \left(1− \frac{k^k} {e^k k!}\right)k, \mbox{ as } n → ∞$$

I would like to understand why this equation holds and how to prove it. Can someone please help me understand the intuition behind this relationship and guide me through the steps to prove it?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_limit_theorem

Comment: If $X\sim B(p,N)$ then $\Pr(X>k)=\frac{N!}{k!(N-k-1)!}\int_0^pt^k(1-t)^{N-k-1}dt$ is a formula that you can check by derivation in $p$ of both members. It may be useful in your problem.